# C# Constructor that takes in two Action<objects> Fails

Tags: c#

There might be an easier way to do what I'm doing but I'm curious as to why I can't call this constructor with two functions.

I'm trying to write some sort of a sequencer wrapper that doe Step1, kick off Step2, kick off Step3, etc.

The program fails when I call the constructor for StepMonitor 
Error I'm getting: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Action

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Step1 step1 = new Step1();
        Step2 step2 = new Step2();
        StepMonitor stepMonitor = new StepMonitor(step1.Step1Go(), step2.Step2Go()); // Fails here 

    }

    public class StepMonitor
    {
        #region Function To Monitor
        Action<object> _objectToMonitor;
        #endregion
        #region Function to Execute on Event
        Action<object> _objectToExecute;
        #endregion
        #region Constructor
        public StepMonitor(Action<object> objectToMonitor, Action<object> objectToExecute)
        {
            _objectToMonitor = objectToMonitor;
            _objectToExecute = _objectToExecute;
            _objectToMonitor += _objectToExecute;            
        }
        #endregion
    }

public class Step1
{
    public event EventHandler StepCompletedHandler;    // the Event
    public Step1()
    {

    }
    public void Step1Go()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter String for Step1");
        string step1 = Console.ReadLine();
        TriggerStepCompleted();
    }
    protected virtual void TriggerStepCompleted()    // the Trigger. Foo calls this to raise the event
    {
        // make a copy to be more thread-safe
        EventHandler handler = StepCompletedHandler;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            // invoke the subscribed event-handler(s)
            handler(this, null);
        }
    }
}

public class Step2
{
    public event EventHandler StepCompletedHandler;    // the Event
    public Step2()
    {

    }
    public void Step2Go()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter String for Step2");
        string step2 = Console.ReadLine();
        TriggerStepCompleted();
    }
    protected virtual void TriggerStepCompleted()    // the Trigger. Foo calls this to raise the event
    {
        // make a copy to be more thread-safe
        EventHandler handler = StepCompletedHandler;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            // invoke the subscribed event-handler(s)
            handler(this, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think Jon got it, but can you clarify what you mean by "it fails"?

Comment: Heads up: This is not the cause of your error, but you have a typo on line two in that constructor. `_objectToExecute = _objectToExecute;` should be `_objectToExecute = objectToExecute;`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're currently *calling* `Step1Go` and `Step2Go` - whereas you want to be using a method group conversion to create `Action` delegates:

```
StepMonitor stepMonitor = new StepMonitor(step1.Step1Go, step2.Step2Go);
```

Additionally, your methods don't take any parameters, so you *either* need to change `StepMonitor` to accept just `Action` instead of `Action<object>` or use an anonymous function to explicitly ignore the parameter:

```
StepMonitor stepMonitor = new StepMonitor(_ => step1.Step1Go(),
                                          _ => step2.Step2Go());
```

Here `_` is just a somewhat-conventional name for a parameter which is ignored. You could also use:

```
StepMonitor stepMonitor = new StepMonitor(ignored => step1.Step1Go(),
                                          ignored => step2.Step2Go());
```

Note that none of this is related to constructors specifically. You'd get the same problem at the moment if you wrote:

```
Action<Object> action = step1.Step1Go();
```

whereas I'm suggesting you should effectively be using one of these forms:

```
Action action = step1.Step1Go;
Action<object> action = ignored => step1.Step1Go();
```

Comment: In addition, `Step1Go` is parameterless, but the delegate is an `Action<object>`, so it's expecting a parameter of type object on Step1X.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare

```
StepMonitor stepMonitor = new StepMonitor(step1.Step1Go, step2.Step2Go);
```

but the signature of the method need to be:

```
public void Step1Go(object c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter String for Step1");
            string step1 = Console.ReadLine();
            TriggerStepCompleted();
        }
```

Otherwise if you want to have Step1Go() parameterless, change your constructor to **Action** instead of

```
 Action<Object>
```